# How to fix 'handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy'?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm working on a small app, that was tested and was working great along the way. When I added new code to have the app send info to my Firebase Realtime Database, it just won't launch my app. It will flash the MainActivity for a split second then goes black.

When I remove the code I entered, it`enter code here` keeps on doing the same. Although the same code (after removal of what I thought was bad) was working before. I've digged through forums, and I haven't found any piece of code that references a dialog box before the activity has finished

```
,,,
/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: 
no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@356e9f5
2019-05-08 07:46:47.891 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor V/FA: 
onActivityCreated
2019-05-08 07:46:47.998 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor 
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token 
android.os.BinderProxy@c10e219
2019-05-08 07:46:48.014 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor V/FA: 
onActivityCreated
2019-05-08 07:46:48.108 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor 
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token 
android.os.BinderProxy@2818389
2019-05-08 07:46:48.116 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor V/FA: 
onActivityCreated
2019-05-08 07:46:48.238 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor 
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token 
android.os.BinderProxy@b4e046d
2019-05-08 07:46:48.254 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor V/FA: 
onActivityCreated
2019-05-08 07:46:48.359 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor 
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token 
android.os.BinderProxy@685e2dd
2019-05-08 07:46:48.383 3306-3306/com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor V/FA: 
onActivityCreated
,,,

,,,java
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    private EditText UserName, FullName, CountryName;
    private Button SaveInformationButton;
    private CircleImageView ProfileImage;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    String currentUserID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);

        UserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_username);
        FullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_full_name);
        CountryName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.setup_country_name);
        SaveInformationButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setup_information_button);
        ProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.setup_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        SaveInformationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                SaveAccountSetupInformation();
            }
        });

    }

    private void SaveAccountSetupInformation()
    {
        String username = UserName.getText().toString();
        String fullname = FullName.getText().toString();
        String country = CountryName.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username))
        {
            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Please enter Username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname))
        {
            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Please enter your full name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(country))
        {
            Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Please enter you country", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Saving information...");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("username", username);
            userMap.put("fullname", fullname);
            userMap.put("country", country);
            userMap.put("status", "Hey There");
            UsersRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        SendUserToMainActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Account created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void SendUserToMainActivity()
    {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);

    }
}
,,,
Build Gradle (App)
,,,
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
,,,

MainActivity
,,,java
package com.fromfire.fantastysurvivor;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.IdpResponse;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;

    String currentUserID;


    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        //Navigation Drawer
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(currentUser == null)
        {
            SendUserToLoginActivity();
        }
        else
        {
            CheckUserExistence();
        }
    }

    private void CheckUserExistence()
    {
        final String current_user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(current_user_id))
                {
                    SendUserToSetupActivity();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void SendUserToSetupActivity()
    {
        Intent setupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
        setupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(setupIntent);
        finish();
    }

    private void SendUserToLoginActivity()
    {
        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment;

        if (id == R.id.nav_leader) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_mypicks) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_tribe) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_results) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_chat) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_donate) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
            mAuth.signOut();
            SendUserToLoginActivity();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
,,,
```

I am expecting to after I have logged in with a user, to have that uID reference to my firebase database, and if there is no user with that uID, that it would redirect them to the SetupActivity class for more info input.

Right now the screen flashes for a split second (Iguess showing my MainActivity) then goes black.

Answer (score 3):

I saved all my code and xml and literally pasted it into a new project, and the problem was gone. Must've run into some really obscure bug on this one.

Comment: Hmm, facing the same issue caused by some dependency that uses google analytics I wonder if it is related.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have granted the permissions required by the app. This fixed the error on my end